# Parsing: How do I strip out Unicode Characters?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote some code to grab the text in between the break elements on this webpage http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=10478

I think i am on the right track but right now i am getting some bad values
Below are my results
[u'2133 Craigs Store Road', u'Afton,\r\n\t\tVA \xa0\r\n\t\t22920', u'Contact Person:', u'Email Address:', u'Website:', u'Phone:  434-882-3150', u'']

I need to figure out how to strip out the unicode from my result values. Can anyone help?

```
r=requests.get('http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=10478')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
tbl=soup.findAll('table')[2]

Contact=tbl.findAll('p')[0]

list=[]
for br in Contact.findAll('br'):
    next = br.nextSibling
    text=next.strip()
    list.append(text)
print list
```

Comment: i dont think in this case `\r\n\t\t` are formatting commands. I think they are unicode characters

Comment: thanks yeah i'm really new to this, i didn't really know what the term was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the replace built-in function that `str` type has.

```
text = next.strip().replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "").replace("\r", "")
```

That way you can replace the `\n\t\r` and replace them with nothing

Comment: i actually used regex = re.sub(r'[\n\r\t\xa0]','',next).strip() to do what you are describing but thank you so much for you feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag
import requests
import re

r=requests.get('http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=10478')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
tbl=soup.findAll('table')[2]

Contact=tbl.findAll('p')[0]

list=[]
for br in Contact.findAll('br'):
    next = br.nextSibling
    regex = re.compile(r'[\n\r\t\xa0]')
    text=next.strip()
    text=regex.sub(' ', next)
    list.append(text)
print list
```

I looked into it some more and figured out i could use regular expressions to take out those values.I still have an issue with spacing 
[u'    2133 Craigs Store Road', u'Afton,    VA      22920', u'Contact Person:  ', u'Email Address: ', u'Website:  ', u'Phone:  434-882-3150', u' ']
But at least the characters are gone